How to boot windows 10 on UEFI mode after converting the disc from mbr to gpt using mbr2gpt.exe?
After the conversion a uefi partition was created on my main disk used for booting windows. However when I change the settings of my bios right after power-on to allow booting from (only UEFI), it tries to run windows OS and an error message is displayed. The error states a missing or corrupted file(winload.exe). On the other hand, if I change the bios to legacy mode and boot it works normally and the winload file exists. I'm trying to prepare my environment to update to windows 11 once windows 10 is discontinued.

Are you sure it says "winload.exe" and not "winload.efi"?

“If I change the bios to legacy mode and boot it works” - This means MBR2GPT failed to do the conversion. It is impossible to boot Windows in Legacy mode with a GPT disk.

Yes, I took a picture. It says \system32\winload.exe. And the cmd prompt said the conversion was made from mbr to gpt
